# React - State array deleting last item in array instead of specified index

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array state filled with objects called items:

```
    const [items, setItems] = useState([{name: "", toppings: []}])
```

However when I try to delete a specified index with this function:

```
const removeItem = (index) => {
    setItems(items.filter((item, i) => i !== index))
    areItemsCompleted()
}
```

It works when I print the elements to the console **outside of the function**, however the item is not rendering properly.  It only removes the last element of the array from the jsx but the `items` array has the correct values.  I read somewhere that react only checks for changes in state shallowly so it does not check the content of the object it is deleting.  However, I am unsure as to why it shows up in the console that `items` have the correct value but the components arent rendering the correct data.  (Instead it renders the same data except for the last element in `items`).

I have tried multiple ways of deleting elements from my array such as

```
const removeItem = (index) => {
    let arr = [...items]
    arr.splice(index, 1)
    setItems(arr)
    areItemsCompleted()
}
```

How would I delete an element from my array full of objects and render the proper data?

Comment: Is it possible to get a working sandbox demo with the minimal problem?  I think there's too much going on here to automatically know the solution -- i.e., maybe it is `setItems()` that is broken, and `filter()` works fine?  I'm not sure, but a sandbox would help.

Comment: Sounds like you're using the array index as the `key` for the mapped JSX.

Answer (score 5):

So I was using the array index as the `key` prop of the component, but that doesn't work when deleting an item in the array.

React doesn't know which key to delete, as the array index will still exist even after that particular element has been deleted.

**Solution**

Use a unique key for each element in the array. Something like `id` which react can see has been deleted.

Comment: this solution solved my problem.
I generated an `id` (use `Math.random()`) for each item and set it as `key`

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to guess;

Check, may be you are re-setting items somewhere later;

Plus functional form is safer:
`setItems(lastItems=>lastItems.filter((item, i) => i !== index))`

Comment: I just checked, and I am not re-setting the state somewhere else since the only other function in the method is to change a different state.  I tried the code above and sadly it did not work.  (It gave correct output in the console but did not render the components still)